# Move files from parent to subdirectory using java

Tags: java

Hi I am trying to copy the files and folders from root folder to subfolders which are upto level 5.It has to work same if the folders or files need to added.

I have tried some examples regarding level parametric and able to list directories and Suggest me the approach to get the output folder,files structure.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

     String path = "Workspace/MainFolder/";
    String targetPath="/Workspace/Dest/";
    Files.walk(Paths.get(path),5).forEach(p->{
        if(p.toFile().isDirectory()){
            Stream.of(new File(path).listFiles()).filter(File::isFile).map(f->new File(f.getPath().replace(path,targetPath))).forEach(f->{
                f.getParentFile().mkdirs();
                try {
                    Files.copy(p,f.toPath(),StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            });
        }else{
            try {
                Files.copy(p,new File(p.toFile().getPath().replace(path,targetPath)).toPath(),StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
  }
 }
```

Comment: Do you want to overwrite existing files?

Comment: `Files.walk(Paths.get(path),5).filter(p->p.toFile().isDirectory()).forEach(p->Stream.of(new File(path).listFiles()).forEach(f->Files.copy(p,f.toPath())))` Does this work?

Comment: Right after the declaration of `path`. You shouldn't even need your other code.

Comment: I am getting this error java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException:Workspace/MainFolder/.DsStore and java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException:Workspace/MainFolder/FolderA

Comment: You need to enable overwriting of existing files like that: `Files.walk(Paths.get(path),5).filter(p->p.toFile().isDirectory()).forEach(p->Stream.of(new File(path).listFiles()).forEach(f->Files.copy(p,f.toPath(),CopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTONG)))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this solution?

```java
package q63242312;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class RecCopyWithRoot {

    private static boolean deleteDirectory(File directoryToBeDeleted) {
        File[] allContents = directoryToBeDeleted.listFiles();
        if (allContents != null) {
            for (File file : allContents) {
                deleteDirectory(file);
            }
        }
        return directoryToBeDeleted.delete();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String from = "./from";
        String to = "./to";
        try {
            File srcFile = new File(from).toPath().toAbsolutePath().toFile();
            File targetFile = new File(to).toPath().toAbsolutePath().toFile();
            if (!deleteDirectory(targetFile)) {
                //throw new IllegalStateException("cannot delete output directory");
            }
            copyFolder(srcFile.toPath(), targetFile.toPath());
            
            try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(srcFile.toPath(), 5)) {
                stream.filter(p -> p.toFile().isDirectory()).forEach(dir -> {   
                    Path tmpDir=dir;
                    //System.err.println(tmpDir);
                    while((tmpDir=tmpDir.getParent()).toFile().getAbsolutePath().startsWith(srcFile.getAbsolutePath())) {//TODO while has parent
                        
                        for (File f : tmpDir.toFile().listFiles()) {//TODO srcFile.listFiles() --> all from root to dir
                            if(f.isFile()) {
                                System.out.println("res: "+dir+" | "+srcFile+" | "+f);
                                System.out.println(f.getName()+" --> "+targetFile.toPath().resolve(srcFile.toPath().relativize(f.toPath())));
                                try {
                                    Files.copy(f.toPath(), new File(targetFile.toPath().resolve(srcFile.toPath().relativize(dir)).toFile(), f.getName()).toPath(), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    
                });
            }
            for (File toDelete: targetFile.listFiles()) {
                toDelete.delete();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void copyFolder(Path src, Path dest) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(src + "-->" + dest);
        if (src.toFile().isDirectory()) {
            try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(src)) {
                stream.forEach(source -> {
                    Path newDest = dest.resolve(src.relativize(source));
                    if (!newDest.toFile().exists()) {
                        try {
                            Files.copy(source, newDest, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            //Files.copy(src, dest, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219258/discussion-on-answer-by-dan1st-copy-files-from-root-folder-to-subfolder-upto-lev).